# IOS getting results of js file

Tags: javascript, ios, json, cocoa-touch

I have to get some data from the web but given url is a js file. When I get data from the url, what I get is html and javascript codes. When I open the page in a browser, I get the json data as expected but how can I manage to get this json data in IOS environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can point it at a UIWebView and read the contents of the view when it's done loading.  Your delegate will receive a `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)view` call when it's completed loading.

```
NSString *url = @"http://www.newyorktimes.com/page/contents.js";
[webView loadRequest:
    [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
        [NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
```

In your webViewDidFinishLoad use:

```
NSString *contents = [view stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: 
                                         @"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

Comment: nice answer, I thought the same way after posting the question but isn't it overkill to get a view for this ?

Comment: The problem is getting the javascript interpreted.  I can't think of any other way of getting the code to run and therefore return the JSON data.  At least not one that wasn't hacky. :)

Comment: thanks, I think you are right, I can't think any other solution too. Problem is the person who gave me the js file to interpret instead of the data directly. What is wrong with him -_-